# Adding next row fields to previous row in mySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with unix timestamp, userID, Long and lat. I would like to copy the value of Long and Lat from the following row and add them to that row. Please see below.

```html
<table style="width: 645px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="140" />
    <col width="57" />
    <col span="7" width="64" />
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl66" width="140" height="21">Unix Time Stamp</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="64">Long</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="64">Lat</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl67" align="right" width="140" height="20">1458119939</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">-26.2004</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">28.01277</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="21">1458119940</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">26.20654</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">28.04565</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="20">1458128756</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0065</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88437</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="20">1458128757</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0067</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88465</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="20">1442829381</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0064</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88458</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="21">1442829397</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl73" align="right" width="64">-29.0062</td>
      <td class="xl78" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl74" align="right" width="64">29.88436</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl69" align="right" width="140" height="21">1442830988</td>
      <td class="xl73" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl75" align="right" width="64">-26.2065</td>
      <td class="xl79" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl76" align="right" width="64">28.04565</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl65" colspan="3" height="20">Query Result needs to look like</td>
      <td class="xl65">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl65">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl65">&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl66" height="21">Unix Time Stamp</td>
      <td class="xl66">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66">Long</td>
      <td class="xl66">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66">Lat</td>
      <td class="xl66">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66">LongB</td>
      <td class="xl66">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl66">LatB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl67" align="right" width="140" height="20">1458119939</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">-26.2004</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">28.01277</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">26.20654</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">28.04565</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="20">1458119940</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">26.20654</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl70" align="right">28.04565</td>
      <td class="xl70">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0065</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88437</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="20">1458128756</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0065</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88437</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0067</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88465</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="20">1458128757</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0067</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88465</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0064</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88458</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="21">1442829381</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl71" align="right" width="64">-29.0064</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl72" align="right" width="64">29.88458</td>
      <td class="xl77" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl73" align="right" width="64">-29.0062</td>
      <td class="xl78" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl74" align="right" width="64">29.88436</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="xl68" align="right" width="140" height="21">1442829397</td>
      <td class="xl71" width="57">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl73" align="right" width="64">-29.0062</td>
      <td class="xl78" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl74" align="right" width="64">29.88436</td>
      <td class="xl78" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl75" align="right" width="64">-26.2065</td>
      <td class="xl79" width="64">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="xl76" align="right" width="64">28.04565</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So, what is `following row`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT timestamp, userID, Long, Lat, Long as LongB, Lat as LatB FROM table
```

I think you meant column instead of row